# Defining attr_accessor for class instance variables - Ruby

Tags: ruby, attr-accessor, instance-eval

I am trying to create an accessor for a class instance variable. I am calling the `attr_accessor` method from a module which is included in the class. See the code below:

```
module Persistence
  def self.included(mod)
      mod.extend ClassMethods
      # Add accessor for class instance variable
      class << mod
          attr_accessor :persistent_data
      end
  end

  module ClassMethods
      def X
          persistent_data = 'data'
      end
  end
end
```

The above code works. However when I change the code which calls `attr_accessor`, to this:

```
 mod.instance_eval do
     attr_accessor :persistent_data
 end
```

I get `` NoMethodError: undefined method `persistent_data=' ``

Shouldn't both ways work the same or is my understanding wrong here? I am using REE 1.8.7

Comment: `attr_accessor` is an instance method and defines instance methods. So it has to be executed in a context where defining *instance* methods is actually defining a class method. And because class methods are actually singleton methods, you have to execute it in the singleton class.

Comment: ActiveSupport provides `cattr_accessor` which defines both a class method and an instance method to access the same value. (See also its [rdoc](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Class.html#method-i-cattr_accessor) and ActiveSupport [guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_support_core_extensions.html#cattr_reader-cattr_writer-and-cattr_accessor).) If you have ActiveSupport, use it; if not, its implementation might still be useful as inspiration.